# Create pyramids for GeoTIFF files from QGIS

Tags: qgis, gdal, image-pyramids

For a large number of GeoTIFF files I would like to create pyramids using the GDAL > Raster miscellaneous > Build overviews (pyramids) Processing tool (gdaladdo) set up as follows:

[image]

The algorithm finishes without any problems (obviously, cp. log)...

[image]

...but there is not *.ovr file written, nor can I see pyramids in the raster layers properties:

[image]

[image]

I can create pyramids from the raster layer properties > Pyramids panel without any problem, but for 700+ files this is not the way of my choice.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: those are tifs with world files not GeoTiffs so I don't think you can add overviews to them, try to convert them to GeoTiffs first (gdal_translate) and try again

Comment: Jochen Schwarze is back (ist wieder da) :)

Comment: Certainly it is possible to create overviews for baseline tiffs. The issue must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not directly documented but `-clean` (that `Remove all existing overviews` option in QGIS triggers) is meant **only** for removing existing overviews and it is not to be used together with overview creation. Indirectly it can be guessed from https://gdal.org/programs/gdaladdo.html

> <levels>
>
> A list of integral overview levels to build. Ignored with -clean
> option.

Run build overviews first with `-clean` and create new overviews after that with a separate run. If you have external overviews you can simply delete `*.ovr`

I think that the QGIS user interface has a bug and it should disable other options when the `Remove all existing overviews` is selected. And I think that there is a bug in GDAL as well, it does not report in any way that it is just going to delete existing overviews without creating new ones.

```
gdaladdo baseline.tif -r cubic -ro -clean 2 4 8 16 32 64 --debug on
GDAL: GDALOpen(baseline.tif, this=0000022674DA5500) succeeds as GTiff.
GTiff: ScanDirectories()
GTiff: File open for read-only accessing, creating overviews externally.
GDAL: GDALDefaultOverviews::OverviewScan()
GDAL: GDALClose(baseline.tif, this=0000022674DA5500)
```